# ¿Alguna forma de usar los "alias" en una misma consulta SELECT? ¿O algo parecido?

Tags: mysql, select

Mi duda es la que expongo en el título. Tengo que usar alias creadas en una consulta SELECT en esa misma consulta.

Esto es debido a que hago varias transformaciones (que consisten en, básicamente, crear columnas nuevas dentro de una vista) en la vista, y estas transformaciones comprenden varias líneas de código ("IFNULL" gigantes, etc.).

Pongo un ejemplo:

- **Tabla de prueba:**

```
CREATE TABLE `mitabla` (`id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `edad` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salario` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

- **Datos insertados:**

```
INSERT INTO mitabla (nombre, edad, salario) 
VALUES ("Pedro", 24, 21000), ("Maria", 26, 24000), ("Juan", 28, 25000), ("Luis", 35, 28000), 
("Monica", 42, 30000), ("Rosa", 43, 25000), ("Susana", 45, 39000);
```

-**Ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer:**

```
CREATE VIEW Prueba AS 
SELECT *, 
IF(nombre LIKE "M%", "Comienzan con M", "nombre") AS Nombres_M, 
IF(Nombres_M = "Maria", "Encontramos a María!", Nombres_M) AS Nombre_Maria
FROM mitabla;
```

-**Error:**

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Nombres_M' in 'field list'

¿Alguna idea para hacer esto o algo parecido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una subconsulta:

```
SELECT *,
       IF(T.Nombres_M = "Maria", "Encontramos a María!", Nombres_M) AS Nombre_Maria
       FROM (
              SELECT *, 
                     IF(nombre LIKE "M%", "Comienzan con M", "nombre") AS Nombres_M
                     FROM mitabla
       ) T
```

La subconsulta "materializa" la nueva columna y el `select` externo ya está en condiciones de usar ese nombre. Por supuesto, esto tiene cierta penalidad en performance que debiera ser mínima.

Comment: Suena bastante interesante! Pero no aparece el "Encontramos a Maria" en la columna, no sé a que puede ser debido

Comment: Seguramente un tema de datos, revisa si hay o no acentos o un tema de codificación, o espacios de más o de menos